# AWS cloudWatch logs insight, sum the key/value pairs in json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I need some help with the cloud watch insight query that can sum up the key/value pairs in JSON form in logs.

```
fields @timestamp, @message | filter @message like /CTS/
```

After this, how do I parse the JSON and sum the key/values

Logs look like this

```
2022-10-28 16:58:14,685 :INFO: CTS {'aa': 135, 'bb': 187, 'cc': 14, 'dd': 8, 'ee': 3, 'ff': 1} CTE
2022-10-28 16:49:11,397 :INFO: CTS {'aa': 101, 'bb': 153, 'gg': 11, 'ii': 17, 'jj': 2, 'pp': 1, 'zz': 5} CTE
....
...
..
```

I need to sum up the pairs to make a pie chart.
like aa: 236, bb: 240 .....